# Bash integer comparison

Tags: bash, comparison, integer

I want to write a Bash script that checks if there is at least one parameter and if there is one, if that parameter is either a 0 or a 1.

This is the script:

```
#/bin/bash
if (("$#" < 1)) && ( (("$0" != 1)) ||  (("$0" -ne 0q)) ) ; then
    echo this script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter.
fi
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" $0
```

This gives the following errors:

```
./setTouchpadEnabled: line 2: ((: ./setTouchpadEnabled != 1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "./setTouchpadEnabled != 1")
./setTouchpadEnabled: line 2: ((: ./setTouchpadEnabled -ne 0q: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "./setTouchpadEnabled -ne 0q")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are running your script using `sh ./setTouchpadEnabled` instead of using bash.

Comment: @jordanm are you referring to the lack of a bang in the shebang line?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This script works!

```
#/bin/bash
if [[ ( "$#" < 1 ) || ( !( "$1" == 1 ) && !( "$1" == 0 ) ) ]] ; then
    echo this script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter.
else
    echo "first parameter is $1"
    xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" $0
fi
```

But this also works, and in addition keeps the logic of the OP, since the question is about calculations. Here it is with only [*arithmetic expressions*:](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

```
#/bin/bash
if (( $# )) && (( $1 == 0 || $1 == 1 )); then
    echo "first parameter is $1"
    xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" $0
else
    echo this script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter.
fi
```

The output is the same<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ ./tmp.sh 
this script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter.

$ ./tmp.sh 0
first parameter is 0

$ ./tmp.sh 1
first parameter is 1

$ ./tmp.sh 2
this script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter.
```

<sub>*[1] the second fails if the first argument is a string*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much, the error is because the command is xinput and not input

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't stick with the arithmetic expressions also used in the question? I.e. use of `((` and `))`.

Comment: @user828193: well clearly this is about calculations, so arithmetic expressions are *the* way to go. Which is why I found it irritating that you changed this aspect of the question in your answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: You are right! Here it is with arithmetic expressions. I guess I got carried off by the `-ne` and the comparison to a possibly empty string in the OP's code...

Answer (score 19):

Easier solution;

```
#/bin/bash
if (( ${1:-2} >= 2 )); then
    echo "First parameter must be 0 or 1"
fi
# rest of script...
```

**Output**

```
$ ./test 
First parameter must be 0 or 1
$ ./test 0
$ ./test 1
$ ./test 4
First parameter must be 0 or 1
$ ./test 2
First parameter must be 0 or 1
```

**Explanation**

- `(( ))` - Evaluates the expression using integers.
- `${1:-2}` - Uses parameter expansion to set a value of `2` if undefined.
- `>= 2` - True if the integer is greater than or equal to two `2`.

Comment: +1, this exposes and works around a not-great behaviour of the `((` command, which assigns the value of 0 to an empty or unset variable.

Answer (score 9):

The zeroth parameter of a shell command is the command itself (or sometimes the shell itself). You should be using `$1`.

```
(("$#" < 1)) && ( (("$1" != 1)) ||  (("$1" -ne 0q)) )
```

Your boolean logic is also a bit confused:

```
(( "$#" < 1 && # If the number of arguments is less than one…
  "$1" != 1 || "$1" -ne 0)) # …how can the first argument possibly be 1 or 0?
```

This is probably what you want:

```
(( "$#" )) && (( $1 == 1 || $1 == 0 )) # If true, there is at least one argument and its value is 0 or 1
```

Comment: This is an improvement, thank you. It however still gives me errors:
./setTouchpadEnabled: line 2: ((: != 1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "!= 1")
./setTouchpadEnabled: line 2: ((: != 0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "!= 0")

Comment: The quotes aren't strictly necessary inside `(( ))`, but they make StackOverflow's highlighting smarter.

Comment: @Cheiron I think you misunderstood my comment. Take another look at my answer.

Comment: Oh wow, I was indeed doing boolean logic wrong. It still gives me errors, though:
./setTouchpadEnabled: line 2: ((: 0 && (  == 1 ||  == 0 ) : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 1 ||  == 0 ) ")

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered, but here's mine just because I think case is an under-appreciated tool. (Maybe because people think it is slow, but it's at least as fast as an if, sometimes faster.)

```
case "$1" in
    0|1) xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" $1 ;;
      *) echo "This script requires a 1 or 0 as first parameter." ;;
esac
```

Comment: That is nice and clean. Note also the evaluated variable in a case statement is one of those places where you can safely leave it unquoted.