# check if parameter is integer with numeric expression

Tags: regex, bash

The following program checks if the first parameter is a number, or a not a number. The best I could come up with so far is:

```
#/bin/bash
if (( $# )) && (( $1 != 0 )) ; then
    echo "number"
else
    echo "not number"
fi
```

- This works for numbers like `1`, `-1`, `100`, etc, for strings `a`, `abc`, `a431`, or if no parameter is given.
- It *works with a warning* for strings like `1a1`, `1.3`, `-1.2`
- But *FAILS* (obviously) if the parameter is `0`

How could this be fixed? (using arithmetic expressions)

Related: [Bash integer comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511295/bash-integer-comparison)

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
#/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    echo "number"
else
    echo "not number"
fi
```

If you wanted it to handle floating point, you could tweak it easily enough:

```
#/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ || "$1" =~ ^-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ ]] ; then
    echo "number"
else
    echo "not number"
fi
```

Comment: yes this passes all the test I could think of. Not accepting yet though waiting for better answers (if any).

Answer (score 2):

You can press the `printf` built-in command to do the job:

```
if printf "%d" ${1:-foo} > /dev/null; then
    echo "number"
else
    echo "NOT a number"
fi
```

`printf` exits with non-zero status if the conversion fails. The `${1-...}` notation
provides a known not-number if `$1` isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use something like

```
if [ $1 = "$(echo $1 | awk '{print strtonum($0)}')" ]; then
echo "number"
else
echo "not number"
fi
```

Comment: Yes this would work. But I will give it some time in case someone will be able to solve it with the above constrains.

Comment: Also it throws a warning if no parameter is given and identifies floats as numbers

Answer (score 1):

Solution using extended globs

```
#/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $1 = *[0-9]* && $1 = ?([+-])*([0-9])?(.*([0-9])) ]]; then
    echo "Is a number"
else
    echo "Not a number"
fi
```

**Output**

```
$ ./test -1
Is a number
$ ./test 0
Is a number
$ ./test 1
Is a number
$ ./test a
Not a number
$ ./test -1.2
Is a number
$ ./test 0.0
Is a number
$ ./test 1.2
Is a number
$ ./test a.b
Not a number
```

Comment: Plus 1 for prompting more people to Google extended globbing. Minus 1 (IMHO) for the additional complexity, and a regex-style matcher that can't be directly translated if the script gets ported to something other than Bash. Granted, YMMV.

Comment: I disagree, this solution is no more complex or harder to port than yours.

Comment: Globbing is Bash-only syntax that doesn't quite match standard regex structure. I didn't say it was vastly more difficult, just that there's a certain utility in KISS when you don't specifically need Bash-specific features, and can use a generalized regex structure instead.

Comment: But not to worry, it's not like an answer is going to be chosen on this question anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to test for what is not a number:

```
if (( $# )) ; then
  if [[ $1 == *[^0-9]* ]] ; then
    echo "Not a number"
  else
    echo "Is a number"
  fi
fi
```

Note that the above is actually testing only for positive integers. Add +-. to the character class and it will work, sort of, for positive/negative integers and decimal fractions. I say sort of because it would pass 123.456.789 as a number, but it's not valid. You'd need to add additional logic to weed out misplaced or multiple signs and decimal points (and strings like "+", ".", etc.).